# Yocto Snapshot in Time

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto project that I want to freeze in time. As I understand it every time I run bitbake, if a recipe is designed in a way that the latest git repo is pulled, my project with download and build the latest changes. I am sure there is a mixture of repos in the build environment that use a specific git checkout and some that always grab the latest.

I am wondering, is there a way to tell bitbake to ignore updates?

Answer (score 2):

If you set BB_NO_NETWORK = "1" you'll quickly find out which recipes are trying to use the latest revision and can correct that.